# Keep table 100% width after hiding empty columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the table to have `table-layout:fixed;` and `<colgroup></colgroup>`.

After hiding columns, I want my table width to be 100%. But my table width gets smaller. How can I get my table to maintain 100% width? Here is my code:

[Jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nwyqjddv/)

```js
$( "#button1" ).click(function() { hide('table1'); });
$( "#button2" ).click(function() { show('table1'); });

function hide(tableid)
{
 $('#'+tableid+' th').each(function(i) {
  var bool = true;
      var tds = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
      tds.each( function(j) { 
   if (this.innerHTML != '') {bool=false;return false;}; 
  });
  if (bool) 
  {
            $(this).hide();
   tds.hide();
  }
 });
}

function show(tableid)
{
 $('#'+tableid+' th').each(function(i) {
  var bool = true;
      var tds = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
      tds.each( function(j) { 
   if (this.innerHTML != '') {bool=false;return false;}; 
  });
  if (bool) 
  {
            $(this).show();
   tds.show();
  }  
 });
}
```

```css
#table1 {width:100%; table-layout:fixed;}
#table1 td,th{border:1px solid;}

button{margin-top:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
    <colgroup><col><col><col><col></colgroup>    
    <tr><th>th1</th><th>th2</th><th>th3</th><th>th4</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell1</td><td></td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell1</td><td></td><td></td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell1</td><td></td><td>Cell3</td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<button id="button1">Hide</button>
<button id="button2">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try setting `width:100%` to both `th` and `td`.

```css
#table1 th, #table1 td {border:1px solid; width:100%;}
```

```js
$( "#button1" ).click(function() { hide('table1'); });
$( "#button2" ).click(function() { show('table1'); });

function hide(tableid)
{
 $('#'+tableid+' th').each(function(i) {
  var bool = true;
      var tds = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
      tds.each( function(j) { 
   if (this.innerHTML != '') {bool=false;return false;}; 
  });
  if (bool) 
  {
            $(this).hide();
   tds.hide();
  }
 });
}

function show(tableid)
{
 $('#'+tableid+' th').each(function(i) {
  var bool = true;
      var tds = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
      tds.each( function(j) { 
   if (this.innerHTML != '') {bool=false;return false;}; 
  });
  if (bool) 
  {
            $(this).show();
   tds.show();
  }  
 });
}
```

```css
#table1 {width:100%; table-layout:fixed;}
#table1 th, #table1 td {border:1px solid; width:100%;}

button{margin-top:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table1">
    <colgroup><col><col><col><col></colgroup>    
    <tr><th>th1</th><th>th2</th><th>th3</th><th>th4</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell1</td><td></td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td>Cell3</td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell1</td><td></td><td></td><td>Cell4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Cell1</td><td></td><td>Cell3</td><td></td></tr>
</table>

<button id="button1">Hide</button>
<button id="button2">Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#table{
  width:100%!important;
  table-layout:fixed!important;
  min-width:100%
}
```